# htaccess - Rewrite folder to variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I need to Rewrite folder to variable. For example I have a url `http://www.example.com/partners?id=ABC`

I need to get: `www.example.com/partners/ABC`, here "ABC" as id.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^partners/(.*)$ partners/?id=$1
```

Comment: So what is your issue?

Comment: Let us know how it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should try your rules this way in your .htaccess in the root.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

#redirect the old format to the rewritten URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+partners\?id=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /partners/%1? [R=302,L]

#internally rewrite folder to partners querystring. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^partners/(.+)$ partners?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
RewriteRule ^partners/(.*)$ partners?id=$1 [L]
```